# Most efficient way to parse a body of text to match two regexs?

Tags: java, regex

I'm new to Java and want to understand what I'm doing. Is there a more efficient way to program this? I have a body of text in `connectionInfo` that I broke into lines to parse for the matcher. Could I have retrieved the matching text from `connectionInfo` without breaking it into lines? Is this an efficient way to match two strings? Did I need to create two separate Matcher objects for this?

```
// Parse rid and rtoe (estimated time to completion)
String rid = null;
String rtoe = null;
Pattern ridPattern = Pattern.compile("RID = (.*$)");
Pattern rtoePattern = Pattern.compile("RTOE = (.*$)");
Matcher ridMatcher;
Matcher rtoeMatcher;

String[] lines = connectionInfo[0].split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    ridMatcher = ridPattern.matcher(line);
    rtoeMatcher = rtoePattern.matcher(line);
    if (ridMatcher.find()) {
        rid = ridMatcher.group(1);
    }
    if (rtoeMatcher.find()) {
        rtoe = rtoeMatcher.group(1);
    }
}

System.out.println("Request ID: " + rid);
System.out.println("Estimated time to completion: " + rtoe + " seconds");
```

Comment: Well, you could run the regex without splitting them and use a while(ridMatcher.find() || rtoeMatcher.find()). That way you only iterate through actual matches. You just need to make sure to make your regex robust enough to do so without getting extra chars in your groupings.

Comment: Are `RID =` and `RTOE =` at the start of a line? How big is the file?

Comment: Yes, after four spaces, @CasimiretHippolyte, and the file is not big

Comment: You can also not split your file at all, use a single anchored pattern: `(?m)^ {4}(R(?:ID|TOE)) = (.*)`, this way you parse the whole file only once with `find` and you only have to test the capture group 1 to know if it is RID or RTOE. *(You can also use two capture groups to know it faster: `(?m)^ {4}R(?:(ID)|(TOE)) = (.*)`, when group 2 is empty it is RID)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could I have retrieved the matching text from `connectionInfo` without
>   breaking it into lines?

You can match against input strings that contain newlines, so in that sense, yes.  For the `$` anchor to match before line terminators in addition to at the end of the input, you will want to compile your pattern with the `MULTILINE` option, or else put it directly into the pattern.  The `.` metacharacter will not match newlines by default (though there's an option for that), so you don't have to worry about your capturing groups spanning multiple lines.

> Is this an efficient way to match two strings?

It would be more efficient to skip the line splitting and iteration and just match against each pattern once.  It would also be more convenient then to detect the error condition that one or both doesn't match anywhere:

```
Pattern ridPattern = Pattern.compile("RID = (.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Pattern rtoePattern = Pattern.compile("RTOE = (.*)$", Pattern.MULTILINE);
Matcher ridMatcher = ridPattern.matcher(connectionInfo[0]);
Matcher rtoeMatcher = rtoePattern.matcher(connectionInfo[0]);

if (ridMatcher.find()) {
    rid = ridMatcher.group(1);
}  // else error: no RID
if (rtoeMatcher.find()) {
    rtoe = rtoeMatcher.group(1);
}  // else error: no RTOE

System.out.println("Request ID: " + rid);
System.out.println("Estimated time to completion: " + rtoe + " seconds");
```

> Did I need to create two separate Matcher objects for this?

A `Matcher` is specific to a particular `Pattern`, so with the `Pattern`s as you have given them, yes, you need two `Matcher`s.  This is probably not something to worry about, but if the code presented runs so frequently that the performance or amount of garbage produced is a *bona fide* problem, then there are ways you could mitigate it:

- Compile each `Pattern` once only for the whole class, recording it in a static field.  Pattern compilation is comparatively expensive, so this could be a significant win if your code is a bottleneck.
- If and only if the method is protected from concurrent invocation, create a single `Matcher` for each pattern, likewise recorded in static fields, and bind them at need to each new input via their one-arg `reset()` methods.  This will reduce the amount of garbage produced, but it's only worth it if this method is making a significant contribution to a huge problem with GC.

Comment: Thank you! Just what I needed to know.

Answer (score 0):

You're on your way to having a good solution, but there are some small things you can adjust to make it better.

matcher.group(1) will return null if it can't find the pattern, so we don't need to check and make sure that it will find it ( because you are starting at null anyway ). You're correct that we don't need two matchers as well.

```
// Parse rid and rtoe (estimated time to completion)
String rid = null;
String rtoe = null;
Pattern ridPattern = Pattern.compile("RID = (.*$)");
Pattern rtoePattern = Pattern.compile("RTOE = (.*$)");

String[] lines = connectionInfo[0].split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher patternMatcher = ridPattern.matcher(line);
    rid = patternMatcher.group(1);
    patternMatcher = rtoePattern.matcher(line);
    rtoe = patternMatcher.group(1);
}

System.out.println("Request ID: " + rid);
System.out.println("Estimated time to completion: " + rtoe + " seconds");
```

However, you may noticed some repeating code inside the for loop. Generally this is a bad idea. What we can do is make a little helper method to handle that logic:

```
private static String getGroupFromPattern( Pattern pattern, String line ) {
    Matcher patternMatcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    return patternMatcher.group(1);
}
```

Then your original logic would become:

```
// Parse rid and rtoe (estimated time to completion)
String rid = null;
String rtoe = null;
Pattern ridPattern = Pattern.compile("RID = (.*$)");
Pattern rtoePattern = Pattern.compile("RTOE = (.*$)");

String[] lines = connectionInfo[0].split("\n");
for (String line : lines) {
    rid = getGroupFromPattern(ridPattern, line);
    rtoe = getGroupFromPattern(rtoePattern, line);
}

System.out.println("Request ID: " + rid);
System.out.println("Estimated time to completion: " + rtoe + " seconds");
```

We could probably get away with only using a single Pattern object too, but I like the way you have it originally. Only because it is easier to read then a couple String references being feed a Pattern. Hope this helps!

One last note: Are you use you want to be using matcher.group(1)? This will give you the second grouping, and not the first. If you want the first use matcher.group(0), or matcher.group() for short hand.

Comment: There's a difference between not needing two `Matcher`s, and not needing two *variables*.  Your code uses two `Matchers`, as indeed is necessary if there are two distinct patterns to match.

Comment: @JohnBollinger John is correct. I interpreted her asking as "Do I need two variables?", which is incorrect.